# Cannot invoke '-' with with an argument of type(IntegerLiteralConvertible..... (IOS / Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

im getting an error but i dont understand what the issue is. I'm quite new with IOS / Swift development.

```
static func ToDegreesMinutesSeconds(latitude :Double, longitude:Double) -> String{
    println(latitude);
    println(longitude);

    var latDegrees = Int(latitude);
    var latMinutes = 60 * (latitude - latDegrees);
```

I'm not understanding why the compiler is giving me that error. I thank you for your help.

Comment: I would suggest you use the `floor` function instead of `Int` to compute your `latDegrees`.  That way you keep everything as type `Double`.

Comment: Thanks vacawama, i might do that. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
   var latMinutes = 60 * (latitude - latDegrees);
```

to

```
   var latMinutes = 60 * (latitude - Double(latDegrees));
```

Swift doesn't support implicit type casting/conversion.